# Error 405 (Method Not Allowed) when trying to connect to ElasticSearch 7 using React-SearchKit

Tags: reactjs, elasticsearch

I'm trying to connect to ElasticSearch 7 using [React-SearchKit](https://github.com/inveniosoftware/react-searchkit).

I'm following React-SearchKit's official [Connect Your REST APIs guide](https://inveniosoftware.github.io/react-searchkit/docs/connect-your-rest-apis). According to the guide, the ElasticSearch adapter can be configured by passing the following object as a parameter to a `ReactSearchKit` component:

```
const searchApi = new ESSearchApi({
  url: 'http://localhost:9200/search/',
  timeout: 5000
});
```

I'm passing the object to the component as follows:

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <ReactSearchKit searchApi={searchApi}>
          <div style={{ margin: '2em auto', width: '50%' }}>
            <SearchBar />
            <ResultsList />
          </div>
        </ReactSearchKit>
    );
  }
}
```

The problem is that when trying to execute the app I get a 405 error (Method Not Allowed). I don't think there should be a problem sending POST requests to ElasticSearch. What could've gone wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `http://localhost:9200` is your ES-Node, the correct search endpoints in Elasticsearch are:

1. `http://localhost:9200/_search` if you want to search all indices
2. `http://localhost:9200/foo/_search` if you want to search the foo index
3. `http://localhost:9200/foo,bar/_search` if you want to search both indices, foo and bar
4. `http://localhost:9200/data*/_search` if you want to search all indices starting with data

You are missing the _ (underscore).

Here is the related documentation: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-body.html